# Can oral bacteria be targeted by white blood cells?

Tags: immunology, bacteriology, inflammation

Today I was told from a dentist that a leukocyte is much larger than a bad bacterium. So a leukocyte cannot remove bad bacteria when they hide in very places like the space between the gums and teeth for example, because leukocytes cannot exit the body.

So am I right that a colony of bad bacteria cannot be removed from the oral cavity by leukocytes, because they are too big to exit the gum?

Comment: A colony in the gums or teeth are protected by building a strong film around them. There are leukocytes in the mouth, but they can't really breach this strong barrier. It has nothing to do with size.